# How to fetch a subset of an enumeration

Tags: java

Most of the times an enumeration containing all elements is shown in a drop down in the user interface. We have a need to show only 2 out of 5 fields in the user interface. What would be an easier way to fetch this data, by somehow leveraging the same functions available for an enumeration.

```
enum Color {RED, GREEN, BLACK, BLUE, YELLOW};
```

We have a requirement to show only {RED, BLUE} in a certain user interface?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
EnumSet<Color> set = EnumSet.of(Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
EnumSet.of(Color.RED, Color.BLUE)
```

see [`java.util.EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

If enum contains some custom methods (e.g., to display `Red` instesd of `RED`)

```
public enum Color {
    RED("Red"), GREEN("Green"), BLACK("Black"), BLUE("Blue"), YELLOW("Yellow");

    private final String display;

    private Color(String display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display;
    }

    public static EnumSet<Color> getSubSetOfValues() {
        return EnumSet.of(RED, BLUE); // return Red and Green
        //return EnumSet.range(GREEN, BLUE); // return Green, Black and Blue
    }
}
```

*Color.values();* // all elements.

*Color.getSubSetOfValues();* // subset