# Display a subset of an enum in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum Risk {
    LOW(10),
    MEDIUM(20),
    HIGH(30);
}
```

and a managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    public Risk[] getRisks() {
        return Risk.values();
    }
}
```

Now I can display the values in a `<p:selectOneMenu>`

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
     <f:selectItems value="#{data.risks}"
                    var="t"
                    itemValue="#{t}"
                    itemLabel="#{texts[t.name]}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

However what If I wanted to show not all values but only a set of them, e.g. `LOW` and `MEDIUM`, how can I do this?

Comment: Is it permanent or conditional? If conditional, which conditions exactly? All in all I think you ultimately need this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932034/how-to-conditionally-render-an-fselectitem-tag/

Comment: it is permanent. The problem is that I don't know how I can select only one item of my Risk enum. How can I say: itemValue="#{data.risk.LOW} ?

Comment: Just create a new array with the value removed? Not really JSF.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid that

Comment: A fixed subset of an enum is part of the model. So why do it in the view? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786125/how-to-fetch-a-subset-of-an-enumeration. Or just 'disable' the ones that are not to be used like BalusC stated...